# Does Google have access to keystrokes on our Android device keyboard?

Tags: privacy, android, google, instant-messaging

I am using an end-to-end encrypted messenger on my smartphone. However, today I asked myself if the content of the messages is really secure because of the keyboard on my Android device.

As you know, the keyboard makes suggestions for words and also saves some previously written words.

So my question is if Google has access to the words I type on my keyboard or if this suggestion-system is offline-only?

Answer (score 3):

According to their [confidentiality statement](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6380730?p=Gboard_iOS&rd=1), Google doesn't collect anything from what you type when using GBoard, except the searches you make using the G button (for an obvious reason, they need the search terms to perform the search). Suggestions are based on an internal dictionary AFAIK. You can also delete the stored words at any time in the options of the keyboard app.